# HTTP GET usando localhost

Tags: apache-cordova, http-request, onsen

Estou criando um aplicativo usando phonegap + framework onsen que vai ser alimentado por Web Services (RestFul).

Porém não estou conseguindo fazer com que haja uma conversa entre ambas as partes.

Minha chamada ao Web Service está assim:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/WhereToJamServer/ws/colacao/getDataAtual', {})
    .success(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    })
    .error(function() {
        alert('error');
    });
```

E meu Web Service está assim:

```
@Path("/colacao")

@GET
@Path("getDataAtual")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String getDataAtual() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    return sdf.format(new Date());
}
```

Se eu alterar **localhost** para **10.0.2.2** ou pelo IP local (IPv4) da minha máquina também não funciona.

OBS: Quando chamo a URL pelo navegador funciona normalmente.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Os testes estão sendo realizados em um emulador ou em um aparelho real?

Comment: em um aparelho real

Comment: Quando chama a URL pelo navegador *da sua máquina* ou *do aparelho real*?

Comment: Quando chamo a URL pelo navegador do meu PC funciona normalmente. Pelo celular não cheguei a testar. Quando eu chegar em casa vou testar isso também.

Comment: Achei a solução .... editei o post!

Comment: Só uma dica, @vogeloco: o procedimento geral para quando você mesmo acha a solução é responder a própria pergunta e aceitar a resposta, assim fica claro no sistema que a pergunta foi respondida.

Comment: It's done @fsanches, valeu!

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUÇÃO**

Consegui conectar no meu localhost somente alterando minha URL de **localhost** para o endereço **IPv4** da minha **Wifi**.

Para conseguir esse endereço é abrir o **Prompt de Comando** do windows e digitar **ipconfig**. O IPv4 que vc deve procurar é da sua Wifi (**Adaptador Ethernet Ethernet**).

```
 http://DIGITEAQUI:8080/WhereToJamServer/ws/colacao/getDataAtual
```

Antes não tinha conseguido porque coloquei o IPv4 do meu **Adaptador Ethernet Conexão local** (mais conhecido como cabo). Nem me liguei.

E o melhor de tudo é que nem precisa do cabo para acessar o Web Service =)

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser um problema de crossdomain, verifica a whitelist da sua aplicação phonegap, da uma olhada na documentação oficial =

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html

Se mesmo assim continuar o erro, posta aqui qual o retorno da requisição $http.get, qual erro consta.